# Progress of Build in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I was thinking about writing a plugin for Visual Studio and I want to know whether it is possible to know the time left (May not be prefect but atleast approximate) for the build process to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no estimated remaining time in the build system. Other systems like TeamCity usually store metadata about build times and keep a rolling average so as the build/project changes, the expected time to completion can be adjusted accordingly.

You'll probably need your plugin to keep that data somehow alongside the project/solution rather than specifically in the plugin since folder paths could change, if the project is in source control it could be checked out elsewhere, etc. Unless, of course, you're not planning on keeping the data across VS restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Best way seems to be - measure first build time of solution and then compare current one with it.

No ideas about technical side how to do that.